# Class() takes no argument TypeError in python / pygame

Tags: python-3.x, class, pygame

I'm trying to get into pygame, made a class for the middle ground of my level (this is in a modules file):

```
class LevelMg():
    def __inti__(self, data):
    
        self.tile_list = []
        
        cave_tile = pygame.image.load("block_fond_cave.png")
        grotte_tile = pygame.image.load("block_fond_grotte.png")
        
        row_num = 4
        for row in data:
            col_num = 0
            for col in data:
                if col == 1:    
                    img = pygame.convert(grotte_tile)
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_num * 128
                    img_rect.y = 720 - row_num * 128
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                elif col == 2: 
                    img = pygame.convert(cave_tile)
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_num * 128
                    img_rect.y = 720 - row_num * 128
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_num += 1
            row_num -= 1
```

This should take a list of lists containing numbers which represent a different images of tiles and return a list of tuples containing the image and the rect (coordinates and area).

So then i do this (in the level.py file):

```
level_mg_data = [
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
    [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1],
    [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
    [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]
level_mg = LevelMg(level_mg_data)
```

But this gives me the error mentioned, i've been trying to figure it out but i'm out of ideas,
the tutorial i'm following does it the same way but it's 2yrs old so i don't know if anything could have changed synthax wise in this lapse of time, also the class is defined in a "modules" file and is used in a "level" file.

I tried doing :

```
class LevelMg():
    def __inti__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.tile_list = []
```

The result is unchanged

modules.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Player:
    def __init__(self, image, pos_x, pos_y, speed):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert()
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
        self.speed = speed
        self.pos = self.image.get_rect().move(pos_x, pos_y)

    def move(self, right=False, left=False, up=False, down=False):
        if right and self.pos.center[0] < 1280:
            self.pos.right += self.speed
        if left and self.pos.center[0] > 0:
            self.pos.right -= self.speed
        if up and self.pos.center[1] > 0:
            self.pos.top -= self.speed
        if down and self.pos.center[1] < 720:
            self.pos.top += self.speed


class LevelMg():
    def __inti__(self, data):
    
        self.tile_list = []
        
        cave_tile = pygame.image.load("block_fond_cave.png")
        grotte_tile = pygame.image.load("block_fond_grotte.png")
        
        row_num = 4
        for row in data:
            col_num = 0
            for col in data:
                if col == 1:    
                    img = pygame.convert(grotte_tile)
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_num * 128
                    img_rect.y = 720 - row_num * 128
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                elif col == 2: 
                    img = pygame.convert(cave_tile)
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_num * 128
                    img_rect.y = 720 - row_num * 128
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_num += 1
            row_num -= 1
```

level.py:

```
import pygame, sys
from modules import Player, LevelMg

pygame.init()

size = width, height = (1280, 720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
bg = pygame.image.load("sky_night.png").convert()
bg_offset = 0
player = Player("sprite_perso_idle/sprite_0.png", 0, 0, 4)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
tile_size = 128
level_mg_data = [
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
    [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1],
    [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
    [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]
level_mg = LevelMg(level_mg_data)
print(level_mg.tile_list)

run = True
while run:
    
    screen.blit(bg, (0 + bg_offset, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    input = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if input[pygame.K_z]: player.move(up=True)
    if input[pygame.K_s]: player.move(down=True)
    if input[pygame.K_q]: player.move(left=True)
    if input[pygame.K_d]: player.move(right=True)
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.blit(player.image, player.pos)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: `__inti__`? The name of the constructor hat to be `__init__`

Comment: bruh i'm too sleep deprived thanks tho